# Javascript regex to get substring, excluding a pattern?

Tags: javascript, regex, substring

I am still a beginner :)

I need to get a substring ignoring the last section inside `[]` (including the brackets []), i.e. ignore the `[something inside]` section in the end.

*Note -* There could be other single occurances of `[` in the string. And they should appear in the result.

**Example**

Input of the form -

```
1 checked arranged [1678]
```

Desired output -

```
1 checked arranged
```

I tried with this

```
var item = "1 checked arranged [1678]";

var parsed = item.match(/([a-zA-Z0-9\s]+)([(\[d+\])]+)$/);
                          |<-section 1  ->|<-section 2->|

alert(parsed);
```

I tried to mean the following -

**section 1** - multiple occurrences of words (containing literals and nos.) followed by spaces

**section 2** - ignore the pattern [something] in the end.

But I am getting `1678],1678,]` and I am not sure which way it is going.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

OK here is the problem in your expression

```
([a-zA-Z0-9\s]+)([(\[d+\])]+)$
```

The Problem is only in the last part

```
([(\[d+\])]+)$
 ^        ^
 here are you creating a character class, 
 what you don't want because everything inside will be matched literally.

((\[d+\])+)$
 ^      ^^
here you create a capturing group and repeat this at least once ==> not needed

(\[d+\])$
   ^
  here you want to match digits but forgot to escape
```

That brings us to

```
([a-zA-Z0-9\s]+)(\[\d+\])$
```

See it [here on Regexr](http://regexr.com?2uce6), the complete string is matched, the section 1 in capturing group 1 and section 2 in group 2.

When you now replace the whole thing with the content of group 1 you are done.

Answer (score 1):

You could do this

```
var s = "1 checked arranged [1678]";

var a = s.indexOf('[');

var b = s.substring(0,a);

alert(b);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/jasongennaro/ZQe6Y/1/

This `s.indexOf('[');` checks for where the first `[` appears in the string.

This `s.substring(0,a);` chops the string, from the beginning to the first `[`.

Of course, this assumes the string is always in a similar format

Comment: But there could be other single occurances of `[` in the string. sorry I missed that in the question

Comment: No problem @Sandeepan Nath.  If the test is always before the first occurance of `[` then this will still work.

Answer (score 1):

```
var item = '1 check arranged [1678]',
    matches = item.match(/(.*)(?=\[\d+\])/));

alert(matches[1]);
```

The regular expression I used makes use of a [positive lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) to exclude the undesired portion of the string. The bracketed number must be a part of the string for the match to succeed, but it will not be returned in the results.

Answer (score 0):

Here you can find how to delete stuff inside square brackets. This will leave you with the rest. :) 
[Regex: delete contents of square brackets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5410652/regex-delete-contents-of-square-brackets)

Answer (score 0):

try this if you only want to get rid of that [] in the end

```
var parsed = item.replace(/\s*\[[^\]]*\]$/,"")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var item = "1 checked arranged [1678]";
var parsed = item.replace(/\s\[.*/,"");
alert(parsed);
```

That work as desired?

Answer (score 0):

Use escaped brackets and non-capturing parentheses:

```
var item = "1 checked arranged [1678]";
var parsed = item.match(/([\w\s]+)(?:\s+\[\d+\])$/);
alert(parsed[1]); //"1 checked arranged"
```

Explanation of regex:

```
([\w\s]+)    //Match alphanumeric characters and spaces
(?:          //Start of non-capturing parentheses
\s*          //Match leading whitespace if present, and remove it
\[           //Bracket literal
\d+          //One or more digits
\]           //Bracket literal
)            //End of non-capturing parentheses
$            //End of string
```