# PCRE regex to remove empty braces

Tags: regex, perl, pcre

How can one write a regex to remove all pairs of braces that contain nothing?

For example, `{}` and `{{}}` should be reduced to an empty string, but `{{}` becomes `{` and `{{A}{}}` becomes `{{A}}`.

I'm currently running `s/\{\}//g` in a loop until the string length is fixed, but is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Matching balanced pairs is one of the most difficult regex problems. Fortunately, PCRE has an extension to deal with it. This answer might help. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5410652/regex-delete-contents-of-square-brackets

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Matching balanced pairs using traditional regular expressions is difficult, if not impossible.  Fortunately PCRE and others have an extension to match recursively, `(?R)` will recursively match the entire pattern.

```
/\{(?R)*\}/
```

That says to match brace pairs which have zero or more brace pairs inside them. See [perlretut->Recursive patterns](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlretut.html#Recursive-patterns) and [perlre->Extended Patterns->?R](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#Extended-Patterns) for more information.

Answer (score 2):

Without recursion:

```
1 while s/\{\}//g;
```