# Perl Regex match balanced parentheses

Tags: regex, perl, braces

Following strings - match:

```
"MNO(A=(B=C) D=(E=F)) PQR(X=(G=H) I=(J=(K=L)))" - "MNO"
"MNO(A=(B=C) D=(E=F))" - "MNO"
"MNO" - "MNO"
"RAX.MNO(A=(B=C) D=(E=F)) PQR(X=(G=H) I=(J=(K=L)))" - "RAX.MNO"
"RAX.MNO(A=(B=C) D=(E=F))" - "RAX.MNO"
"RAX.MNO" - "RAX.MNO"
```

Inside every brace, there can be unlimited groups of them, but they have to be closed properly.

Any ideas? Don't know how to test properly for closure.

I have to use a Perl-Regular-Expression.

Comment: Are you sure you want to do this with regex? This will be recursive regex and, therefore, its not the best way to resolve the matter. Using classic solution via stack is much easier.

Comment: This is possible in some regex flavors. Which one are you using?

Comment: @Itay have to use Regex

Comment: @RaphaelH Good luck but that's not the best practice

Comment: Also please clarify this in your question and I'll retract the duplicate flag.

Comment: Why not match `PQR` in the first and fourth line? It's outside of any parentheses.

Comment: Like previous commenters said, it depends on the flavour. .Net can do it using balancing groups, see http://blog.stevenlevithan.com/archives/balancing-groups for a really good overview.

Comment: Using Perl-Regular-Expression

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4445674/can-i-use-perl-regular-expressions-to-match-balanced-text

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Perl or PHP, for example, you could use a regex like

```
/\((?:[^()]++|(?R))*\)/
```

to match balanced parentheses and their contents.

See it on [regex101](http://regex101.com/r/sE5wY2).

To remove all those matches from a string `$subject` in Perl, you could use

```
$subject =~ s/\((?:[^()]++|(?R))*\)//g;
```

**Explanation:**

```
\(       # Match a (
(?:      # Start of non-capturing group:
 [^()]++ # Either match one or more characters except (), don't backtrack 
|        # or
 (?R)    # Match the entire regex again, recursively
)*       # Any number of times
\)       # Match a )
```

Comment: @RaphaelH: This regex works in Perl or PCRE (Perl-compatible regular expressions).

Comment: +1 Nice one. This is also mentioned in [perldoc perlre](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#%28?_PARNO_%29-%28?-_PARNO_%29-%28?+_PARNO_%29-%28?R%29-%28?0%29). It would be nice with a more detailed explanation.