# Regular Expression to find text between two open and close brackets by ignoring other brackets

Tags: python, regex, perl

```
method void run() {
        var char key;
        var boolean exit;

        let exit = key;

        while (exit) {
            // waits for a key to be pressed.
            while (key) {
                let key = key;
                do moveSquare();
            }

            if (key) {
                let exit = exit;
            }
            if (key) {
                do square.decSize();
            }


            // waits for the key to be released.
            while (key) {
                let key = key;
                do moveSquare();
            }
        }

        return;
 }
```

I would like to have a regular expression to capture only the entire body of first while loop (with other while and if statements ). I tried : \while\s*(.+)\s*{(.+?)}\ but the while's closing bracket is excluded. Only take the first } it encounters is considered.

Comment: Can you not use a proper parser for whatever language that is?

Comment: I am trying to write a parser for jack. I am trying to extract the contents of the while loop. I am able to do it for a single while loop but, for nested while loops my regular expression doesn't work.

Comment: http://regex101.com/r/aN5qK5/1

Comment: Writing a parser is an annoyingly difficult problem. I don't think it's one you'll be solving with a regex.

Comment: Duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4445674/can-i-use-perl-regular-expressions-to-match-balanced-text

Comment: there's what purports to be a full BNF for jack at http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/sasha/2010/12/12/writing-a-compiler-in-c-parsing-part-4/ that looks pretty simple; you need to pick a language (python or perl) and then see what tools that language gives you to take something BNF-like and generate a parser.

Answer (score 1):

Regular expressions can't cope with nested recursive structures. For those, you'll need something more powerful.

In these simple "I just want to extract a substring" cases I often have good luck with [`Text::Balanced`](http://metacpan.org/pod/Text::Balanced) and its `extract_bracketed` function.

For a larger case of wanting an actual recursive parser, I build [`Parser::MGC`](http://metacpan.org/pod/Parser::MGC) for that purpose.

Either of these should do fine.

Comment: False. One can use recursive regular expressions for parsing small strings containing nested parantheses.

Answer (score -1):

you can try this one too :

```
/^(\s*)while.*{[^]*\1}/igm
```

you can try it [here](http://regexr.com/39vqg)

Comment: So you make the indentation syntactical? Not sure whether this is brilliant or asinine.