# perl, matching balanced parens using .Net regex

Tags: perl

I needed some perl code to match balanced parens in a string.

so I found this regular expresion code below from .Net and pasted it into my **Perl** program thinking the regex engine was similar enough for it to work:

```
 /
           \s*\(
           (?: [^\(\)] | (?<openp>\() | (?<-openp>\)) )+ 
           (?(openp)(?!)) 
           \)\s*
        /x
```

My understanding of how this regex works is a follows:

1. **Match first paren:**

```
\(
```

2. **Match pattern a, b, or c at least once:**

```
(?: <a> | <b> | <c>)+
```

where a, b, and c are:

- a is any character that is not a paren

```
[^\(\)]
```

- b is character that is a left-paren

```
\(
```

- c is  character that is a right-paren

```
\)
```

and:

- b is a capture group that pushes to named capture "openp"

```
(?<openp>\()
```

- c  is a capture group that pops from named capture "openp"

```
(?<openp>\()
```

3. **reject any regular expresssion match where openp doesn't equal zero items on stack:**

```
(?<-openp>\))
```

**4. match end paren**

```
\)
```

---

Here's the perl code:

```perl
sub eat_parens($) {
    my $line = shift;    
    if ($line !~ /
           \s*\(
           (?: [^\(\)] | (?<openp>\() | (?<-openp>\)) )+ 
           (?(openp)(?!)) 
           \)\s*
        /x)
    {
        return $line;
    }    
    return $';
}

sub testit2 {
    my $t1 = "(( (sdfasd)sdfsas (sdfasd) )sadf) ()";
    $t2 = eat_parens($t1);
    print "t1: $t1\n";
    print "t2: $t2\n";
}

testit2();
```

Error is:

```
$ perl x.pl
Sequence (?<-...) not recognized in regex; marked by <-- HERE in m/\s*\((?: [^\(\)] | (?<openp> \( ) | (?<- <-- HERE openp> \) ) )+ (?(openp)(?!) ) \) \s*/ at x.pl line 411.
```

Not sure what's causing this.... any ideas?

Comment: You're trying to use a complicated  regular expression written for one dialect (C#/.net) with a different dialect (perl). Naturally there's going to be issues.

Comment: See https://perldoc.perl.org/perlre#(?PARNO)-(?-PARNO)-(?+PARNO)-(?R)-(?0)

Comment: @Shawn , I had some question about this link.  I noticed the regex has a "foo" in the middle of it... would i need to remove that to make it purely match parens?

Comment: Yes, you'd have to adjust the bit(s) that match literal strings as appropriate.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can I use Perl regular expressions to match balanced text?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4445674/can-i-use-perl-regular-expressions-to-match-balanced-text)

Comment: I don't see `(?<-...)` in the [.NET reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/regular-expression-language-quick-reference). Could you provide docs for it?

Comment: (?<name>pattern) 
Captures the specified pattern into the specified group name. The string used for the name must not contain any punctuation and cannot begin with a number.  https://regexhero.net/reference/

Comment: `(?<-...)` is not mentioned in that linked document either. It's a copy of the official docs I previously linked with stuff removed. So again I ask, could you provide docs for it?

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way to do it:

```perl
/
   (?&TEXT)

   (?(DEFINE)
      (?<TEXT>
         [^()]*+
         (?: \( (?&TEXT) \)
             [^()]*+
         )*+
      )
   )
/x
```

It can also be done without naming anything. Search for "recursive" in perlre.

Comment: what does (?&TEXT) do? also what does (?(DEFINE) ... ) do?

Comment: Matches using pattern defined as `TEXT`. [perlre](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlre)

Comment: I;m not familar to with *+  being used together also

Comment: Prevents backtracking. Again, [perlre](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlre)

Comment: *+ prevents backracking?

Comment: No, the `+` does. It prevents `*` from matching less than max. It's an optimization here.